# Terraform split all object in a list while using count.index

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform code like below.

```html
locals {
 org_sub_accounts = [
   "111111111111",
   "222222222222,
   "333333333333",
 ]

 role_arns = [
   "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/DataConnector1",
   "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/DataConnector2",
   "arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/DataConnector3",
 ]
}


resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack" {
  count               = length(local.org_sub_accounts)
  account_id          = local.org_sub_accounts[count.index]
  region              = "ap-east-1"
  parameter_overrides = {
RoleName = local.role_arns[count.index]
  }
  stack_set_name      = aws_cloudformation_stack_set.stackset.name
}
```

My problem is my `RoleName` should be `DataConnector` potion (after /) but not the entire ARN in the `aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance`. How can I pass the RoleName `DataConnector*` within each index?

Note, here I defined the variables in the locals to show my use case. But actually those comes from other resource outputs.

Comment: So you need all three roles or only one in the `RoleName`?

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE. As the code loops through the index, I want to pass each Role name. So there will be three stack instances get created and each one having RoleName `DataConnector1`, `DataConnector2` , `DataConnector3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the `split` built-in function:

```
locals {
  role_names = [for arn in local.role_arns : split("/", arn)[1]]
}
```

With this part `split("/", arn)[1]` you are splitting the IAM role ARN into two parts (before and after the `/`) and with the index `[1]` you are effectively getting the second part of that list. Then, you would have to change the code to reflect that with:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack" {
  count               = length(local.org_sub_accounts)
  account_id          = local.org_sub_accounts[count.index]
  region              = "ap-east-1"
  parameter_overrides = {
    RoleName  = local.role_names[count.index]
  }
  stack_set_name      = aws_cloudformation_stack_set.stackset.name
    }
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split